# Unable to use the copy of default master page by making some changes to it

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I am taking the copy of the v4.master and changing its **Compatible UI Version(s)** to 15 and publishing it so that i can chose it as my site master page. Every thing works fine as of now. But when i am making the changes to master page and save it it throws an error.[image: Issue with master page customization]

Comment: What changes are you making? Please try to be more specific

Comment: I was just editing and saving it. I am not making any changes to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is the issue with my current webapplication. But I have created new web application and same is working fine.